# postgresql queries with expression

Tags: postgresql

I create this table 'friend' with PgAdmin III. I would like to select all the data where the word 'grand' is contained in the columns keywords.

I tried the following:
SELECT * FROM friend where keywords LIKE '*grand*';

but it does not work, i don't receive any results.

Would someone have any ideas ? 
Thank you

[image: Postgresql table 'friend']

Answer (score 0):

Use wildcards:

```
select * 
from friend 
where keywords like '%grand%';
```

Read more [in the documentation.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE)